# Magento: SEO friendly urls for pagination and product limiting

Tags: magento, pagination, seo

I want to make the pagination urls and the product limiting urls SEO friendly. Currently it is appearing as `SiteURL/categoryURL/?page=2 and SiteURL/categoryURL/?show=15`
which is the default behavior of magento. But I want the urls to be like `SiteURL/categoryURL/page/2 and SiteURL/categoryURL/show/15`.

Any tutorial on this or any free extension that will do it. Any guideline or tutorial on how to achieve this. Anything will work except the paid extensions there are many which can do it but I am not willing to purchase the extension. I am willing to do it myself or any free extension that will do the job or at least one thing that I require.

Comment: use  canonical meta tag most of the search engine is following this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/canonical-meta-tag

Comment: This wont change the URL, it will just add the canonicals,

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this Aleem?  I am trying to sort this at the moment

Comment: There are some extensions whcih does that, but the paid ones and expensive. Luckily my client purchased that for me.

Comment: From official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.